# Problems with SoundManager 2

Tags: javascript, html, soundmanager2

I am trying to implement [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/getstarted/) to play snippets of songs on [this page](http://www.transalpine.ch/portale/culturale/tempo_libero/9_81.php).
This is my current JavaScript code:

```
alert('c!');
soundManager.url = 'http://www.transapine.ch/common/soundmanagerv297a-20120513/swf/soundmanager2.swf';
soundManager.flashVersion = 8; // optional: shiny features (default = 8)
soundManager.useFlashBlock = false; // optionally, enable when you're ready to dive in
/*
    Example HTML to make sound snippet:
    <div>
        <a href="http://path.to/soundclip/sclip.mp3" class="sclip hidden"><img src="..." height="x" /></a>
    </div>
*/

alert('d!');
soundManager.onready(function() {
    alert('e!');
    var els = $.Elements.getElementsByClassName('sclip');
    var a = url = '';
    var clips = new Array();
    var masterVolume = 100;

    for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
        a = els[i];
        url = a.href;

        clips[i] = soundManager.createSound({
            id: "clip" + i,
            url: url,
            volume: masterVolume
        });//clips[i] = soundManager.createSound({

        $.Events.add(a, "click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            clips[i].play();
        });//$.Events.add(el, "click", function() {

        $.CSS.removeClass(a, 'hidden');// show the button

    }//for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
});//soundManager.onready(function() {
```

And this is the section in the HTML page calling the necessary scripts:

```
<script src="http://assets.momo40k.ch/common/js/$-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">alert('a!'); //these alerts are for debugging</script>

<script src="http://assets.momo40k.ch/common/soundmanagerv297a-20120513/script/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">alert('b!');</script>

<script src="http://assets.momo40k.ch/common/js/soundclips.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">alert('f!');</script>
```

**Note:** the [$ library](http://assets.momo40k.ch/common/js/%24.js) is a small library I use to even out the browser differences.

I have encountered several problems with this.

### 1. SWF files

In SoundManager's tutorial it says to use `soundManager.url` to tell it the location of the SWF files it needs. Whatever value I gave it, it seemed to ignore it, as Firebug gave me the following error:
`NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.transalpine.ch/portale/soundmanager2.swf`
So I tried putting `soundmanager2.swf` in `http://www.transalpine.ch/portale/`, and the error disappeared, so I continued to see if I could get it to work like this.

**Note:** I have a base tag setting `http://www.transalpine.ch/portale/` as the base URL in this section of the site.

Problems 2 and 3 sort of happened at the same time, I only managed to separate them through debugging the script little by little...

### 2. Script doesn't execute in certain conditions

After that, nothing happened. The two testing buttons I had put on the page weren't appearing as they should be (`$.CSS.removeClass(a, 'hidden');` removes the class `hidden` from the elements, effectively showing them), so I went about working out what was executing and what wasn't in my usual way: alerts!
So I found out that `soundclips.js` wasn't executing at all, and then I found out that it could execute as long as lines 28-32 (`clips[i] = soundManager.createSound({...});`) were commented out. That puzzled me: how can something the browser hasn't even read yet prevent from reading that whole file?!

### 3. `soundManager.onready` doesn't fire

Having removed those lines, I still had a last problem, though probably it's caused by problem 1: the event `soundManager.onready` never fires.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my setup, and what's causing all these problems?
I'm guessing 2 and 3 both derive from 1, but I really don't understand 1 nor how 2 can be...
Thank you!

Comment: I've similar problem soundmanager2 works fine only in two pages and on other pages it appends soundmanager.swf to the curent url

Answer (score 0):

First off the URL should look like this:

```
soundManager.url = 'http://www.transapine.ch/common/soundmanagerv297a-20120513/swf/';
```

Everything else should somewhat be fixed now.

Comment: I see! Thanks, I will try this as soon as possible!